# How not to use body style css rule in part of html code?

Tags: css, html, styles

I have this `body` style CSS rule . I wonder how I could **keep the rule**, but only not use it for a part of my code that starts immediately after `<body>`? The code that starts immediately after the `<body>` is around 5 hyperlinks,just one below each other .

At this moment the current CSS formats the hyperlink size and fonts which I don't want; is there a way that these hyperlinks have their own font or size or have default values (basic format) ? How can this be done ?

CSS rule:

```css
body {
  direction: ltr;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  color: #555;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

code after `<body>`:

```html
<a href="./link1.html">link1</a>  <br />
<a href="./link2.html">link2</a>  <br />
<a href="./link3.html">link3</a>  <br />
<a href="./link4.html">link4</a>  <br />
<a href="./link5.html">link5</a>  <br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific rules override general rules in CSS. The basic example is below:

```css
body {
  direction: ltr;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  color: #555;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
  z-index: 1;
}
    
a {
  font-size: 42.5%;
}
```

### Update

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="example">
  <a href="./link1.html">link1</a>  <br />
  <a href="./link2.html">link2</a>  <br />
  <a href="./link3.html">link3</a>  <br />
  <a href="./link4.html">link4</a>  <br />
  <a href="./link5.html">link5</a>  <br />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  color: #555;
}

#example a {
  font-size: 42.5%;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply . should i put a {font-size:42.5%;} inside the css or it can be placed inside head ? Is there a way to place all these links in div and in css specify that keep default font and size for that specific div ? if this can be done could you guys shoe me how i can declare such div and its css rule ?

Comment: You can place your CSS in the head inside <style> tags, but it's not recommended - it's better to keep your CSS in an external file and reference it from your HTML <head>. Yes, I will just update my answer now.

Comment: @user1788736 Here's your update. you can either use #example {} as the selector if you want everything in the div with the color red, or  #example a {} if you want all the links inside that div turned red.

Comment: many thanks guys. user125697 and ssilas777 could i specify default font size and default blue size for hyperlinks inside those div rules (what i mean by default is just if i dont use css specify font and size in hyperlink itself)? i tried to change font size to 100 percent it is still smaller ! i can increase further ?

Comment: @user1788736 I don't understand what you mean? If you want to specify the default font-size for all links, just use something like this: a { font-size:14px; }

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this.
If you want to have all hyperlinks in your HTML in different fonts you can specify:

```css
a {
  font-size: 5px;
}
```

Or if you want to make a certain set of hyperlinks only to have different fonts:

```html
<div id="menu">
   <a href="./link1.html">link1</a>  <br />
   <a href="./link2.html">link2</a>  <br />
   <a href="./link3.html">link3</a>  <br />
   <a href="./link4.html">link4</a>  <br />
   <a href="./link5.html">link5</a>  <br />
</div>
```

Now in CSS

```css
#menu a {
  font-size: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that these hyperlinks have their own font or size

Just write a CSS ruleset with a selector that matches the links, and rules that change the font and/or font size.

> or have default values(basic format) ?

No.

Comment: could u should me how i can write such css rulset that keeps default font and size for these sets of hyperlinks?

Comment: No. You can change the style to whatever you like, but there isn't a way to say "whatever the default was" (since the default is "What the parent is").